# Add workflowControlEndpoint to all hosted workflow services

Tags: workflow, workflow-foundation-4, workflowservice

Is there any way to add this endpoint to all .xamlx workflow services hosted in an IIS site? We allow users to generate dynamic workflow services so we don't have wcf endpoints configured in a web.config. I want some way of adding the control endpoint to all hosted workflow services without having to alter the web.config each time a service is created by a user.

Comment: Did you find a way to do that ? I tried to use Behavior to add endpoint and i think that would work in general but in my case I was trying to add WorkflowControll endpoint and i didn't have much luck with that.